# How can I test a view with a form in Django?

Tags: python, django, forms, testing, view

I am creating an application in Django and I have the next problem: I want to write a test for a view in Django, but that view receives a form from the html, and I don't know how could I simulate the sending of a form to test that view.

My view is the next one:

```
class EnsaioaBilatuViewTest(TestCase):

def test_ensaioa_bilatu_view(self):

    self.client.login(username='admin', password='admin')

    response = self.client.post('/url/', {'attr1':'2015-01-01', 'attr2':''})

    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 302)

    self.assertEquals(response.context['value'], 0)
```

The error I get is the next one:

```
 self.assertEquals(response.context['value'], 0)
 eError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How does it happen?

Comment: What's your question, exactly? How to send data to a view in a test? This is all very well explained by the [testing documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client).

Comment: I change the post to understand better

Comment: A 302 is a redirect, it wouldn't have a context.

Comment: And why could it be redirecting?

Comment: Because that's what you do after a successful POST, you redirect to another page.

Answer (score 0):

To test the view, supply the data that the HTML form sends back, then assert something on the response:

```
response = self.client.post(reverse('select_self'), 
    {u'form-0-id':[u'1'],
     u'form-0-username': [u'thomas6'],
     u'form-0-class_choice': [u'1'],  
     u'form-1-id':[u'4'],
     u'form-1-username': [u'thomas6'], 
     u'form-1-class_choice': [u'10'], 
     u'form-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
     u'form-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2'], 
                                                        })
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

Comment: I change the post to understand better